# Is it possible to create nested lists?

Tags: discussion

We can create lists, as in:

- hello, and
- world; but

sometimes I want sublists, or in other words "nested" lists. Has this feature been implemented?

Comment: I forgot that this was on meta and was about to give an answer of the form " a list is an ordered n-tuple, and one can contemplate lists of list..."

Answer (score 6):

1. Certainly
2. you

   - can

     - nest
   - lists

     1. as
     2. needed.

Answer (score 5):

Just add different amounts of space before the list marker:

- hello, and

  - sub-hello
- world; but

  - sub-world

Answer (score 5):

- You

  - Can

    - Do

      - So

        - Easily,
      - But

        - Don't

          - Let

            - It

              - Get

                - Out
    - Of
- Hand.